# Chrome: Inspect Element vs View Source

Tags: xml, google-chrome

I am using Chrome 10 to receive a web service response in XML. The request completes successfully.  I then want to view the content of the results.

I go to Inspect Element and see the desired XML.  For curiosity, I also view source.  I am pretty sure the way Chrome works is that Inspect Element is the correct results.

My issue is that the results in Inspect Element and View Source are different. In fact, Inspect Element gives the correct results while View Source provides an error. The error is an authentication error, so the response is still completing but acting like a failure.

Why are they so different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View Source in Chrome sends another request for the file, and since it's not authenticated, it returns the source of the login page. This is different from the way say IE works, where the source is cached and returned when you try to view it.

Inspect Element shows the current DOM's snapshot data. This is what you got from making your initial, authenticated request. So yes, this is the "correct" one.