# chrome: difference page source and inspect element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

what is the difference between the html in  'view page source' and inspect element in Chrome 15? looks like 2 different html?

Comment: duplicate with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572297/chrome-inspect-element-vs-view-source

Answer (score 14):

The view page source page shows you the exact text that was returned by the server. Inspect element actually shows you the fully rendered [DOM tree](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

The DOM tree is slightly different for each browser, depending on the specific quirks and support of features.

Answer (score 2):

I guess code modified/added by JavaScript will be available in Developer tool inspect element.
And code at time of page load can be seen by view source.

Answer (score 0):

View page source opens the file in a separate window, whereas inspect element allows you to modify (locally of course) the code and change css values while the page live-updates.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.: for a little different

1. html page source

```
This is a plaintext <br />
```

2. inspect element

```
This is a plaintext <br>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).