# MVC Model breaks when changing cascading DropDownList values with Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC view with a model, where, when I select something from a drop down list, it does a JSON query to my controller, gets an updated list of items for a second drop down, and repopulates the 2nd drop down with new values. I do this, but building the `<option value="5">Test</option><option value="13">Another</option>....` string, and then set the HTML of the 2nd drop down with that new code:

Javascript:

```
$(".cmbSubCategory").html(result.SubCategoryString);
```

Visually, this is working well. My UI updates nicely.

However, when I save, it seems it doesn't recognise the selected value of the second drop down, which is the one I built.

Once I rebuild a control, that was originally setup by a view model:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SubCategoryId, Model.SubCategories, new { @class = "cmbSubCategory form-control" })
```

.. can I no longer use the selected value in the model, when I do the 'post' back to my controller?

I notice that even after visually, the 2nd dropdown is populated with a few options, when I 'View Page Source', it just shows:

```
<select class="cmbSubCategory form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SubCategoryId must be a number." data-val-required="The SubCategoryId field is required." id="SubCategoryId" name="SubCategoryId"><option value="0">Select a Category</option>
</select>
```

No options.. But in the browser, it shows items...

Edit: Found the issue!

Althought I was populating the HTML and setting the 'Selected' value in the HTML, I wasn't setting the 'val' of the drop down list!

This now works:

```
if (result.Success == 'true') {
                    if (result.SubCategoryString != "") {
                        $('#cmbType').val(result.TransactionTypeId);
                        $('#cmbCategory').val(result.CategoryId);
                        $(".cmbSubCategory").html(result.SubCategoryString);
                        $(".cmbSubCategory").val(result.SubCategoryId);
                    }
                }
```

The last line is the key! `$(".cmbSubCategory").val(result.SubCategoryId);`

I thought building the HTML Selected option would have been enough - but you must also set the 'val' of the combo.

Comment: Please add your controller code and how you are populating a second drop down, via ajax?

Comment: Debug hint: Use 'inspect element' instead 'view page source'. 
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003070/chrome-difference-page-source-and-inspect-element

Comment: Thanks! The debug has helped! When I generate the new SELECT, and set the selected value, I just add a 'SELECTED' word to the <Option> tag. However, when I manually select the value in the drop down, and then inspect, the 'SELECTED' isn't shown in the markup. Maybe I am supposed to set something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a working example.

Please note that the hardcoded values are just for demonstration purposes.

**Model**

```
    public class FooModel
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public List<SubCategory> SubCategories { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubCategory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

**Actions**

```
   public ActionResult Ddl()
    {
        var model = new FooModel();
        var categories = new List<Category>();
        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();

        // Read from db
        categories.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Description = "Cat 1" });
        categories.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Description = "Cat 2" });
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 1, Description = "Sub-Cat 1", CategoryId = 1 });
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 2, Description = "Sub-Cat 2", CategoryId = 2 });

        model.Categories = categories;
        model.SubCategories = subCategories.Where(s => s.Id == 1).ToList();

        // initially set selected
        model.CategoryId = 1;
        model.SubCategoryId = 1;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ddl(FooModel model)
    {
        var subCategoryId = model.SubCategoryId;

        // Send categories back to model etc
        ...

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Json Action**

This filters on the selected id

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetSubCategories(int id)
    {
        var subCategories = new List<SubCategory>();
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 1, Description = "Sub-Cat 1", CategoryId = 1 });
        subCategories.Add(new SubCategory { Id = 2, Description = "Sub-Cat 2", CategoryId = 2 });
        var filteredCategories = subCategories.Where(s => s.Id == id).ToList();
        return Json(filteredCategories, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

**View**

This simply sets an onchange event for the category which loads the options into the sub category list.

```
@model FooModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, new SelectList(Model.Categories.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Description"))
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SubCategoryId,new SelectList(Model.SubCategories.AsEnumerable(), "Id", "Description"))
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var getsubCategoryUrl = '@Url.Action("GetSubCategories")';
    $(function () {

        $('#CategoryId').change(function () {
            var selectedCategory = $('#CategoryId').val();
            if (selectedCategory != null) {
                $.getJSON(getsubCategoryUrl, { id: selectedCategory }, function (subs) {

                    var subSelect = $('#SubCategoryId');
                    subSelect.empty();

                    $.each(subs, function (index, sub) {
                        subSelect.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: sub.Id,
                            text: sub.Description
                        }));
                    });

                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

As the sub category list is picked up by the model binder your selected option will be set in your post.

Comment: I'm unsure where this code fits into my current script. Can you assist? Yes, the field names are 'Id' and 'Description', but I also need to set the Selected value. I do that like this in my Controller at the moment:reply += string.Format("<Option value='{0}' {2}>{1}</option>", item.Id, item.Description, item.Id == tp.DefaultSubCategoryId ? "Selected" : "");

Comment: Hi, I can. I'm not at a PC yet but when I get on I will post an example. The controller returns json objects projected using linq.

Comment: Sorry, I see you solved it now. I can still post the example later if u need it. Just let me know if u do.

Comment: An example would be great. Your way seems better.

Comment: Ok, I will sort one now for you.